# how to hide parent div if child is hidden after select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would hide the parent div class="letter" if its child div class="number" has been hidden after touching a select option.
I try to do this using last lines of script here showed.
To understand better what I'm need of, open up the snippetp preview html file then choose All letter in first select and number 5 in second select. Because  number 5 is not inserted in any Letter Div all Div Letter should be hidden, but they all still showed and empty.

```js
// function to manage select Letter    
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#selectLetter").change(function(){
        $(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
            var optionValueLetter = $(this).attr("value");
            if(optionValueLetter){
                 $(".letter").not("." + optionValueLetter).hide();
                $("." + optionValueLetter).show();
            } else{
                $(".letter").hide();
            }
        });
     }).change();
    
    
    
// function to manage select Number  
    $("#selectNumber").change(function(){
        $(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
            var optionValueNumber = $(this).attr("value");
                if(optionValueNumber){
                    $(".number").not("." + optionValueNumber).hide();
                    $("." + optionValueNumber).show();
                } else{
                    $(".number").hide();
                }
            });
        }).change(); 
     
showAll(); // function to show all div   
        
}); // close $(document).ready(function()   
        
        
// show all div
function showAll(){   
    $(".letter , .number").show();
    }
    
// function to hide parentdiv letter if child div number is diplay="none"   
var children = $(".letter").children($('.number'));
       
    if($(children).css('display') === 'none'){
        $(".letter").hide();
    }else{
        $(".letter").show();
        }
```

```css
.letter{   
border-left:solid 10px;
border-bottom:solid 4px;
color:white;
border-color:#636c72;
background: #636c72;;
margin-left:10px;
margin-right:10px;
width:60%;
}  
    
.number{   
border-left:solid 10px;
border-bottom:solid 4px;
color:white;
border-color:lightblue;
background: rgba(44,159,215, 1);;
margin-left:0px;
width:90%;
} 
    
select{
margin-left:10px;    
width: 30%;
border-left: solid 3px;
border-bottom: 0px;
border-right: solid 0px;
border-color: #cbcbcb;
height: 3em;
color: white!important;
background-color: rgba(44,159,215, 1)!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
    
<title>Test</title>
   
</head>

<body>
    

<select  id="selectLetter" > 
    <option value="letter">All Letter</option>
    <option value="a">Letter A</option> 
    <option value="b">Letter B</option>
    <option value="c">Letter C</option>
    <option value="d">Letter D</option>
</select>
               
      
<select  id="selectNumber"> 
    <option value="number"> All Number</option>
    <option value="1">Number 1</option>   
    <option value="2">Number 2</option>    
    <option value="3">Number 3</option>
    <option value="4">Number 4</option>
    <option value="5">Number 5</option> 
</select>
    
<div class="letter a" >
    <div class="title"><p> div LETTER A </p></div>
    <div class="number 1">  <p> Number 1</p> </div>
    <div class="number 1">  <p> Number 1</p> </div>
    <div class="number 2">  <p> Number 2</p> </div>
    <div class="number 3">  <p> Number 3</p> </div>
    <div class="number 4">  <p> Number 4</p> </div>
</div>
    
<div class="letter b" >
    <div class="title"><p> div LETTER B</p></div>
    <div class="number 1">  <p> Number 1</p> </div>
    <div class="number 1">  <p> Number 1</p> </div>
    <div class="number 2">  <p> Number 2</p> </div>
    <div class="number 3">  <p> Number 3</p> </div>
    <div class="number 4">  <p> Number 4</p> </div>
</div>
    
<div class="letter c" >
    <div class="title"><p> div LETTER C</p></div>
    <div class="number 1">  <p> Number 1</p> </div>
    <div class="number 2">  <p> Number 2</p> </div>
    <div class="number 3">  <p> Number 3</p> </div>
    <div class="number 4">  <p> Number 4</p> </div>
</div>
    
<div class="letter d" >
    <div class="title">  <p>div LETTER D</p> </div>
    </div>
    
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    

    
    
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: var children = $(".letter").children($('.number'));

should be

var children = $(".letter").children('.number');

Comment: Also the whole block of code after the **** function to hide parentdiv letter if child div number is diplay="none"****  comment will only execute once after page load. Change the logic of your code and clean it a bit.

Comment: @hgeorge your div letter D is deliberately empty? what's the expected behavior? If user select `number 1`, what happen to div D?

Comment: @Sudarpo Chong Yes Div D is deliberately empty and because of the logic I need, it should be not be showed at all

Comment: @hgeorge, in that case, my fiddle meets ur requirement :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/sudarpochong/ap3z3r7s/

I simplified your code.

### `Select/dropdown` event handler

```
$("#selectLetter").on("change", selectChangeEventHandler);
$("#selectNumber").on("change", selectChangeEventHandler);
```

#### Function `selectChangeEventHandler`

```
function selectChangeEventHandler(e) {
    var selectedLetter = "." + $("#selectLetter").val();
    var selectedNumber = "." + $("#selectNumber").val();
    filterLetterNumber(selectedLetter, selectedNumber);
    hideLetterDivIfAllNumberDivHidden(selectedLetter);
}
```

#### Function `filterLetterNumber`

```
function filterLetterNumber(letter, number) {
    // console.log("filterLetterNumber", letter, number);
    $(".letter").hide();
    $(".number").hide();
    $(letter).show();
    $(number).show();
}
```

### Function `hideLetterDivIfAllNumberDivHidden`

> would hide the parent div class="letter" if its child div
>   class="number" has been hidden after touching a select option

```
function hideLetterDivIfAllNumberDivHidden(selectedLetter) {

    // console.log("hideLetterDivIfAllNumberDivHidden", selectedLetter);

    if (!selectedLetter || selectedLetter === "") {
    console.log("", selectedLetter);
    selectedLetter = ".letter";
  }

    $(selectedLetter).each(function (index, el) {
    console.log("hideLetterDivIfAllNumberDivHidden", index, el);
    $(this).show();

    //var countHidden = $(el).children(".number:hidden").length;
    var countVisible = $(el).children(".number:visible").length;
    //console.log("countVisible", countVisible, "countHidden", countHidden);

    if (countVisible == 0) {
        $(this).hide();
    }

  });

}
```